# How to send a request to the WooCommerce API

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm currently building a solution for a company as an intern, and I need to use the WooCommerce REST API features in my C++ project to send data to the website.

I've so far, after 2 long painful days, managed to install the cURL library (through vcpkg) and tested the library a bit with the many examples that you can find on the internet. But for now, what I found doesn't seem to match with what the people at WooCommerce put in their documentation.
For example, in [this](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#create-a-product) section, they show how to create a product on the platform using cURL, but I can't understand how to translate it in cURL language inside the C++ project. Heck, the command doesn't even work when I use it in the command prompt with my parameters.

```cpp
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

// cUrl declaration 
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;
    std::string URL = "http://www.example.com";

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        // Check for errors
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            std::string error = "curl_easy_perform() failed: ";
            error += curl_easy_strerror(res);
            error += "\nImpossible de se connecter au site WooCommerce fourni. Veuillez verifier vos paramètres et redémarrer l'application.";
            wxMessageBox(error);
        }
        else {
            std::string success = "Connexion au domaine ";
            success += URL;
            success += " réussie.\nPour changer de domaine, veuillez consulter la page Paramètres.";
            wxMessageBox(success);
        }

    }

    // cleanup
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
```

This code works fine, I know that I have to add the company's website instead of the example, but I can't figure out where to add my client key and client secret (basically like in the example shown on the WooCommerce doc). The basic cURL commands work fine in my local command prompt, but the example doesn't event work.
I know that my request for help may be kind of basic and easy to solve but I just spent the last 2 days and a half working on this and I'm starting to lose it.

Thanks for your help, I tried to speak the best english I could, so sorry in advance for any typo, or sorry if my post doesn't live up to the presentation standards of this platform, I'm kinda new around here :D

Comment: Maybe you should read up a bit on HTTP in addition to curl itself :)

Comment: I've read about it as you told me so, and I think I have unterstood how it works. To sum it up, I know that I have to send a request (of type GET, POST, DELETE,... etc) , like it is done in the documentation. But there is some kind of progress : this morning, when I tried again, the program compiled but curl gave me this error : "Unspported protocol".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out, for those who pass by and may have the same problem as I had. The commands you do with cURL in the terminal and with the library are totally different :

- In the command prompt, you got to enter `curl -X POST https://blablablabla`
- In the C++ library, you have to call the `curl_easy_setopt()` function with parameters to specify each component of the request : `CURLOPT_URL` is your main domain, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is the data you want to POST, and there are other parameters such as `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, `CURLOPT_WRITE_DATA`,... etc. that handles the response from the server.

For me, [this example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html) was really useful, I don't know how I could have missed it :D Thanks Jesper Juhl for the advice, it is crucial to understand how HTTP and HTTPS works to figure this out.